# A strange symptom about mvvmlight listbox SelectedIndex focused color after transition of pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a question about Mvvmlight binding Listbox SelectedIndex.
The full source code can be downloaded [here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=866FAAAC43FA6E14&id=866FAAAC43FA6E14!322).
Here is my precondition:

**[TestModel]**

```
string Title;
string Description;
```

**[TestViewModel]**

```
ObservableCollection<TestModel> TestList;
```

**[xaml binding]**

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding TestList}"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex Mode=TwoWay}">
       .....
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
       .....
       </i:EventTrigger>.....
```

Here is my OnSelectionChanged code:

```
 private void OnSelectionChanged(TestModel test)
    {
        int index = SelectedIndex;
        Debug.WriteLine("[SelectionChanged] +++, index={0}", index);
        // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
        if (-1 == SelectedIndex)
            return;
        Debug.WriteLine("[SelectionChanged] selected item={0}", test.Title);
        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        SelectedIndex = -1;
        Debug.WriteLine("[SelectionChanged] ---, index={0}", index);
    }
```

I have a [sample](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=866FAAAC43FA6E14&id=866FAAAC43FA6E14!322) to have MainPage.xaml and TestPage.xaml.

1. **MainPage**: This page has a button, click the button will navigate to **TestPage**
2. **TestPage**: This page has a listbox and binding to ViewModel

When I run this sample, tap button to **TestPage**, and try to tap any item of Listbox, I can see the item has no **focused color** (because I reset SelectedIndex to -1).

Here comes the question, when I back to **MainPage**, then again tap button to **TestPage**, you will see tapping any item of Listbox will cause **focused color** on every item, it's strange.

Hope anyone can help me to see if any problem on my sample.
Thanks.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the behaviour you describe. Your sample app behaves as expected for me (running in the emulator with the latest SDK updates, etc.)

Comment: Hi Matt,
Thanks for your comment, I will try to use "the latest SDK" later.

Comment: By the way, Matt, the SDK you mean is "WP7 SDK" or "Mvvmlight SDK"?

Comment: I was using 7.1.1 and the version of MvvmLight in your zip file

Comment: My SDK is 7.1 and emulator still has the same problem, I will install 7.1.1 to try later, thanks.

Comment: Hi Matt, after installation of SDK7.1.1, my emulator still has the same problem.
Anyway, still thanks for your test information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a workaround from somebody below:

Change:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
```

To:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
```

It really works as what I expected.
**Tap** can allow user to **tap repeated ListItem**, also "reset SelectedIndex = -1" can make **selected item without highlight color**.